# Java Lambda capture or re execute?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Make a functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public RulesFact {
    Object getPropertyValue(String propertyName);
}
```

An instance a lambda inside a method.

```
public RulesFact rulesFactImpl(Object o) {
    return propertyName->PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o).getPropertyValue(propertyName);
}
```

Is there a difference between this method and the above one? In the above one, does the `PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess` method get called each time the lambda is executed? Is there a difference in thread safety?

```
public RulesFact rulesFactImpl(Object o) {
    BeanWrapper accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o);
    return propertyName->accessor.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
}
```

Javadocs on above reflection utils: [Package org.springframework.beans](https://javadoc.org/spring/5.2.12.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression is executed when `RulesFact.getPropertyValue` is called.

Which means that the first version calls `PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o)` every time `RulesFact.getPropertyValue` is called, which is good if the accessor can change over time.

The second version calls `PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o)` when `rulesFactImpl` is called, and caches the value, which is good for performance, but bad if the accessor can change over time.

*FYI:* The second version can be written using method reference:

```java
public RulesFact rulesFactImpl(Object o) {
    BeanWrapper accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o);
    return accessor::getPropertyValue;
}
```

Comment: And it can be written even shorter, `return PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o) ::getPropertyValue;` without changing the semantics.

Comment: @Holger True, but sometimes I like having intermediate variables for clarity and for debugging purposes. Once JIT is done with the code, it won't make a difference either way. 

Comment: I know, but sometimes people show an astonishing interest in expressing things as one-liner…

Answer (score 1):

Slightly, but probably not in a way you care about, assuming these APIs are reasonably well-written.

```
public RulesFact rulesFactImpl(Object o) {
  return propertyName->PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o).getPropertyValue(propertyName);
}
```

This returns a `RulesFact` that, when called, invokes `forBeanPropertyAccess` and then does whatever work on it. If you call it multiple times, it calls `forBeanPropertyAccess` each time.

```
public RulesFact rulesFactImpl(Object o) {
  BeanWrapper accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o);
  return propertyName->accessor.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
}
```

This calls `forBeanPropertyAccess` once and makes a closure around its value. You can think of this closure as being like an instance variable. We're, in some sense, making a subclass of `RulesFact` which has an instance variable called `accessor` whose value is computed at construction time only once. If we call this lambda several times, `forBeanPropertyAccess` will never get called again; it'll just use the original value several times.

Comment: Both versions "make a closure", though Java doesn't call it that, because it isn't a closure. The first version has closure with `o`, the second version has closure with `accessor`. This answer makes it sound like the first version doesn't make a closure, aka create a *virtual* subclass of `RulesFact`. It does.

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less the same but it's not functionally identical. Suppose `PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(o)` throws an exception.

In the first case, `rulesFactImpl(...)` would never throw. Provided `RulesFact.getPropertyValue` was never called, there would be no exceptions.

In the second case,`rulesFactImpl(...)` would always throw.

Comment: Another functional difference is that first version support the changing of value from the `forBeanPropertyAccess(o)` method, while the second version snapshots the value when `rulesFactImpl(...)` is called, and hence ignores any change-over-time of the accessor value.

Comment: @Andreas Mutable objects 

Comment: It's not about whether the object is *mutable*, but about whether the function is *deterministic*.

Comment: @Andreas It's not really about determinism either. That function could be deterministic, pure and idempotent but if `o` changes outside the context of that function [then it may give different result](https://ideone.com/tkjSDm). Anyway, it was just a flippant remark. It seems like by far the most likely way this function would return a different result is if the state of `o` changed. There are other ways, that's just the most likely

Comment: *"A function is considered deterministic if it always returns the same result set when it's called with the same set of input values"* Determinism is as seen by the caller. Since `o` is effectively final, determinism means that it'll always return the same value. If the object behind `o` is changed so the method returns something else, then the method is non-deterministic. *Any* method that relies on changeable state is by definition non-deterministic, because the state of the object is not considered "input values" to the function, since they are not values input to the function by the caller

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I did suspect that this would come down to different definitions. "*the state of the object is not considered "input values" to the function*" can you find reputable a citation for this? I did try when I was writing my last reply and couldn't find anything one way or another. Intuitively, your definition of determinism is crazy to me.  Determinism is about whether you can *determine* what the output will be given you know the input. Just because the input is a mutable object doesn't mean you don't know what it's state is

Comment: I guess it depends on what `o` is. If `o` is an object created/maintained by the caller directly, then it functions more like a `record` (`struct`), i.e. a POJO with multiple values. Whether mutable or not, it would be considered a (complex) input value. If `o` is an object outside the control of the caller, i.e. because it was injected, then it is opaque, any change of the "state" of the object would break determinism as seen by the caller, whether that state is in fields or from a database.

Comment: Oracle database documentation says: *"Specify `DETERMINISTIC` to indicate that the function returns the same result value whenever it is called with the same values for its arguments."* --- It also says: *"Do not specify this clause to define a function that uses package variables or that accesses the database in any way that might affect the return result of the function."* Package variables are like Java fields, so mutable fields means non-deterministic.

Comment: @Andreas Disagree with the premise that "Package variables are like Java fields". Package variables are more like static fields, if anything. The difference being that the field in my example is accessed via a reference passed in as input. It is *still input*, it is just indirect. That would be different from a function just accessing a static field irrespective of the input. If you can't find a reference from an OO programming language - doesn't even have to be Java - I'm really not interested.

Comment: @Andreas "*I guess it depends on what o is...*" The definition you previously quoted said "*when it's called with the same set of input values*". It did not say "*when the caller can prove that it's called with the same set of values*". So which is it? This new definition you've stated (whether or not the reference was injected and whether or not it it can be considered opaque) is a bit handwavey for my liking.

Comment: Deterministic is as seen by the caller. If the method is deterministic to the caller, then the caller can cache the return value, to improve performance. If the values of `o` are outside the control of the caller, and can change while the caller is invoked, then the method becomes non-deterministic. As I said, it depends on what `o` is.

Comment: @Andreas Found [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/pure-ccs08.pdf) which you may be interested in. See section 3.2 "*There is not a single obviously right answer to these questions. Determinism is thus a parameterized property: **given a definition of what it means for arguments to be equivalent**, a method is deterministic if...*" The bolded part is where we disagree, so it's not a matter of technical accuracy, it's a matter of what definition of equivalence you choose to apply